# Initializing python package pdfbox throws me out of python

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, pdfbox

I used Pip to install `pdfbox`. When I try to `import` it at the REPL, it quits the interpreter:

```
PS D:\AssetExtraction> python
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdfbox
>>> p = pdfbox.PDFBox()
PS D:\AssetExtraction>
```

The relevant environment variables look OK:

```
JAVA_HOME    D:\Python_385\jre\jdk-17.0.5
PDFBOX       D:\Python_385\pdfbox\pdfbox-app-2.0.21.jar
```

I have PDFBox working on other systems with the same setup but can't get it to work on this machine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried updating to 2.0.29 for pdfbox-app.jar?

Comment: I tried with pdfbox-app-2.0.21.jar, pdfbox-app-2.0.28.jar and pdfbox-app-3.0.0.jar but no luck.

Comment: What about a different jdk version?

Comment: I tried jdk-17.0.5 and jre1.8.0_321 but no luck. Are you suggesting any version?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the limit of my understanding of the problem.  Perhaps filing an issue with pdfbox's github page?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the Python wrapper for Apache PDFBox, which is a Java library for working with PDF files. The error you're encountering might be related to the interaction between Python and Java.

**Java Version Compatibility:**
Ensure that your Python environment is compatible with the version of Java you have installed. You mentioned that you have JDK 17.0.5, which seems relatively recent. However, it's worth double-checking that the Python PDFBox library is compatible with this version of Java.

**Library Installation:**
Make sure that the Python PDFBox library is correctly installed. You can check the installation by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

```
pip show pdfbox
```

This will display information about the installed PDFBox package.

**Classpath Configuration:**
Ensure that the pdfbox-app JAR file is in the classpath. The PDFBOX environment variable you've set seems to point to the JAR file. However, you can also add it explicitly to the Python script before importing the pdfbox module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'D:\Python_385\pdfbox\pdfbox-app-2.0.21.jar')
import pdfbox
```

**Error Handling:**
Wrap the import and object creation in a try-except block to catch any exceptions and print more information about what might be going wrong:

```
try:
    import pdfbox
    p = pdfbox.PDFBox()
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

**Check Java Path:**
Make sure that the java executable is in your system's PATH environment variable. You can check this by running java -version in the command prompt. If it's not in the PATH, you may need to add it.